# Check Field Update SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to this one:

```
StockId | Dispatched
--------------------    
1234    | 0
1234    | 1
```

Where `dispatched = 0` until an order comes in for an item of stock, then it changes to `= 1`.

This is fine for generating results for stock for today as you can do a query to display where `dispatched ='0'`. However for older data I would like to see what was in stock on a certain date ie `01/01/2010`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see it as possible given the columns you are showing.  Is there any chance you have an update date column in the table?  That wouldn't be perfect but might help.  Really what you need is a history table and a trigger that populates it every time the Dispatched flag is changed.

Comment: Well, if you don't have some date field on the row, then how can you compate for a date?  You need to create either a separate history/audit table that will retain any changes to the dispatched field.  You could do that with a trigger on your source table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a bit or int flag in that manner, simply change dispatched to be a date or datetime (nullable -- null would equate to your current 0).  Then you can query for any date comparison you'd like.

While the changes to your code should be fairly straightforward, if you can't change the dispatched column, you have some less appealing alternatives:

- Add another nullable column to track the datetime.
- Add a DispatchedAt table with a non-null datetime and a foreign key constraint that references your current table (classic 1NF).
- Add an "archive table" that includes a system-generated datetime, fill it with triggers on your main table.
- Create a new table the way you'd like and create an updateable view that mimics the old table (with the same name) to "fool" your apps.

If this were not just a new feature, but historical data were of dire importance (regulatory audit?), you could potentially check your transaction log or backups to see when changes were made, but such a solution would belong on DBAs.SE.